# Need some help placing form errors using Jörn's validation plugin

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to edit the plug-in so that the form errors are always inserted into a div.class=error-box.
9 times out of 10 the div.error-box will be right after the input but sometimes it will need to be moved. So the idea is wherever div.error-box is, thats where the validation plug-in would generate the error for the individual input.

I know Jörn's plug-in has a feature to specify the error placement, I'm just having trouble figuring out how to tweak it work with what I want to do.

Here is one of the examples of errorPlacement

```
// errorPlacement 
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if ( element.is(":radio") )
        error.appendTo( element.parent().next().next() );
    else if ( element.is(":checkbox") )
         error.appendTo ( element.next() );
    else
         error.append( element.next().next() );
},
```

I had come up with

```
// errorPlacement
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.each.prepend('<div class=error-box"></div>');
},
```

but this seems to be incorrect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/help-with-validation-error-message-placement